# Event delegation and Turbolinks: document or body?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, event-handling, turbolinks, event-delegation

When creating event handlers in a Rails/Turbolinks-enabled app, is it best to delegate to `document.body` or `document`? Is there an accepted convention?

I've read that delegating to `document` is slightly less performant. However, it does allow you to avoid registering `ready` callbacks throughout your javascript codebase. Assume my scripts are in the <head> as is recommended for Turbolinks.

An example using jQuery (although the question isn't really about using jQuery):

```
$(document).on('click', 'selector', callback);

// versus

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document.body).on('click', 'selector', callback);
});
```

Comment: This post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links

Comment: Yeah, I saw this one. If my question was "how can I make my existing js work with turbolinks?" that answer would be acceptable. I'm more interested in how you would implement it if you had no legacy.

Comment: Using `$(document).ready` with Turbolinks willl not work everytime. So you can either listen on events on the `$(document)` directly or use `$(document).on('page:load', callback)`. Therefore `$(document).ready` is not a valid option for you.

Comment: Also I don't think that listening on events this way `$(document).on('click', 'selector', callback);` will work if the HTML element is not yet in the page but loaded later with Turbolinks

Comment: @MrYoshiji Yes it does, that's the point of event delegation. The event is not bound to 'selector' but to document, and whenever the callback is executed the event delegation checks if the original element causing the event corresponds to the given 'selector'.